# Why RegisterCallBack and ros::Spin both don't work?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Refer the code in [velodyne_camera_calibration](https://github.com/robofit/but_velodyne/blob/hydro-devel/but_calibration_camera_velodyne/src/calibration-node.cpp) , when I run the code, it doesn't terminate and has no error but it doesn't continue in the middle(line 198 and line 190). In order to have convenient debug, I add some "cout" to print something.

```
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> image_sub(n, CAMERA_FRAME_TOPIC, 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::CameraInfo> info_sub(n, CAMERA_INFO_TOPIC, 1);
  message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> cloud_sub(n, VELODYNE_TOPIC, 1);

 typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::Image, sensor_msgs::CameraInfo, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> MySyncPolicy;
 Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), image_sub, info_sub, cloud_sub);
 cout << "breakpoint 1 " << endl;
 sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2, _3)); // Add "cout << "breakpoint 2" << endl;" at the beginning of callback function
cout << "breakpoint 3" << endl;
  ros::spin();
cout <<"breakpoint 4" << endl;
```

After I run the code, only "breakpoint 1" and "breakpoint 3" show up. It means that the callback function is  skipped and ros::spin is not implementing.

Can anyone help me figure out where the problem is ? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240932/why-registercallback-and-ros::spin-both-don%27t-work?/) by [KWL](https://answers.ros.org/users/27640/kwl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like this code is fine.

If you're not getting callbacks, you should use rqt_graph or rostopic to confirm that the calibration node is subscribed to the correct topics, and that data is published on all topics. If one of the topics is not present, the synchronizer will never call its callback.

ros::spin() is supposed to block until the program terminates, so that seems to be working properly.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KWL](https://answers.ros.org/users/27640/kwl/) on 2016-08-03**:
Thank you! As you suggest, I checked rqt_graph and found out that the node is not subscribed to the correct topics! :)